# Java ObjectOutputStream / Objectinpustream - object will only sent once as they should

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

i am using ObjectStreams to communicate between server and client. Everything worked fine. But now i got to a point, where i want to send an ArrayList to the client. The Class Card is serializable.

If i sent the ArrayList to the Client for the first time the client get the ArrayList is sent from the server.

If i change the ArrayList on the Serverside and sent it to the client, the client still gets the old one.

Here is the Codesnippets i use :

```
###Server###

for ( CardPlayer cp: players_in_game){
        cp.setHand(new ArrayList<Card>(0));
        System.out.println("Generate an empty ArrayList of Cards for : " + cp.getName() );
        cp.getHand().add(deck.takeCardFromTop()); 
        System.out.println("Add a card to hand of Player : " + cp.getName());
        cp.getHand().add(deck.takeCardFromTop());
        System.out.println("Add a card to hand of Player : " + cp.getName());
        cp.getHand().add(deck.takeCardFromTop());
        System.out.println("Add a card to hand of Player : " + cp.getName());
    }


    for ( CardPlayer cp: players_in_game ){

        String cmd = "updatecards";

        try {
            cp.getOos().writeObject(cmd);
            cp.getOos().flush();
            cp.getOos().writeObject(cp.getHand());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




    for ( CardPlayer cp: players_in_game){


        cp.getHand().add(deck.takeCardFromTop()); 
        System.out.println("Add a card to hand of Player : " + cp.getName());
        cp.getHand().add(deck.takeCardFromTop());
        System.out.println("Add a card to hand of Player : " + cp.getName());

    }


for ( CardPlayer cp: players_in_game ){

        String cmd = "updatecards";

        try {
            cp.getOos().writeObject(cmd);
            cp.getOos().flush();
            System.out.println("Server is sending an ArrayList with "+ cp.getHand().size() +" Cards");
            cp.getOos().writeObject(cp.getHand());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





###Client###

        while (gameIsStillActive) {

            String cmd = (String) ois_game.readObject();

            if (cmd.equals("updatecards")) {
                ArrayList recievedCards = (ArrayList) ois_game.readObject();

                System.out.println(this.name + ": Recieved a ArrayList with  " + recievedCards.size() + " Cards.");

            }

        }

 ###console###  
 Generate an empty ArrayList of Cards for : Harald
Add a card to hand of Player : Harald
Add a card to hand of Player : Harald
Add a card to hand of Player : Harald
Generate an empty ArrayList of Cards for : Stephan
Add a card to hand of Player : Stephan
Add a card to hand of Player : Stephan
Add a card to hand of Player : Stephan
Generate an empty ArrayList of Cards for : Dummy
Add a card to hand of Player : Dummy
Add a card to hand of Player : Dummy
Add a card to hand of Player : Dummy
Harald: Recieved a ArrayList with  3 Cards.
Stephan: Recieved a ArrayList with  3 Cards.
Dummy: Recieved a ArrayList with  3 Cards.
Add a card to hand of Player : Harald
Add a card to hand of Player : Harald
Add a card to hand of Player : Stephan
Add a card to hand of Player : Stephan
Add a card to hand of Player : Dummy
Add a card to hand of Player : Dummy
Server is sending an ArrayList with 5 Cards
Harald: Recieved a ArrayList with  3 Cards.
Server is sending an ArrayList with 5 Cards
Stephan: Recieved a ArrayList with  3 Cards.
Server is sending an ArrayList with 5 Cards
Dummy: Recieved a ArrayList with  3 Cards.
Das Deck hat noch17 Karten
```

Comment: Please check this ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341086/java-socket-serialization-object-wont-update

Comment: Object Streams send graphs rather than trees of data.  It does this by only sending each object once.  If you don't call `reset()` regularly this can also lead to a subtle memory leak.